# My trackpad is collapsing in the front. Is it possible to reseat it?

Tags: trackpad

I have a mid-2011 MacBook Pro that I've used exclusively as a desktop. My righthand uses a wireless trackpad while my lefthand uses the built-in trackpad (in between are two large monitors).

About 2 weeks ago, clicking on the built in trackpad felt weird. And, I had to press harder. I am pretty sure, it went from "fine" to "not so fine" somewhat quickly. I ignored this issue until now.

I just looked closely at the trackpad and am so surprised. The *front/right* corner is very collapsed, but still works (indeed, that is where I always click). The *front / left* is not collapsed, but it is not very responsive and feels weird. I have to press hard.

- Is trackpad collapse a common point of failure in old macbooks?
- Is it possible to reseat the trackpad?
- Is reseating the trackpad something Apple would for me (I'd be willing to pay for it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same thing happen to my 2009 Macbook a few years ago. I was outside of the warranty and AppleCare. Amazingly, I think I found the original YouTube video I used to fix it [HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BdKwE9FOnrI). I recall parts being around $50 to do it myself. Also of note is [THIS](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/how-much-does-a-track-pad-repair-replacement-cost-from-apple.1610377/) thread on MacRumors. It seems to indicate that, back in 2011, Apple may have fixed the trackpad for $100-200. When I had issues with my trackpad, it was because my wrist was laying on it when I typed and I damaged the trackpad. If you read [THIS](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2580325?start=15) article in the Apple Support Communities, some people reported trackpad issues with battery swelling. Some people have reported getting the swollen battery replaced by Apple for free. It may be wise to take it to Apple and have them give you a diagnosis and a price quote before fixing it yourself like I did. I think I just got lucky that it was just the trackpad.